How to simulate hardware keyboard presses
I am trying to send the down arrow key in task manager and it just isnt working. I am coding in c# btw. Is there any way I can do it natively on my language? I tried many different keyboard simulation methods like keybd_event.
The down arrow to work like it does when I press it on my keyboard
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    // Importing keybd_event from user32.dll
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    // Virtual key codes
    const byte VK_CONTROL = 0x11;
    const byte VK_SHIFT = 0x10;
    const byte VK_ESCAPE = 0x1B;

    // Key event flags
    const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN = 0x0000;
    const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;

    static void Main()
    {
        // Open Task Manager
        OpenTaskManager();
    }

    static void OpenTaskManager()
    {
        
        keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0); // push
        keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
        keybd_event(VK_ESCAPE, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);

        keybd_event(VK_ESCAPE, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); // release
        keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    }
}


There doesn't appear to be any attempt to send a Down-Arrow keypress.

Task Manager runs as an elevated app, programs with a Microsoft certificate can do so without displaying the UAC prompt.  Your app probably doesn't, so attempts to inject input are blocked.  Fix

It doesn't work if tried @RaymondChen
It was there but I decided to remove it because it was pointless.

@Developer: If you've removed the code that doesn't work, how can we be expected to see what might be wrong with it? Are other key presses working?

You can use SendInput - example here: How to use SendInput to simulate the UP arrow key press (or other extended keys) - but, as mentioned, you need to have admin rights to do that. You can send the keys to either the TaskManagerWindow class window or the DirectUIHWND class window -- As a note, when you need to debug this elevated application, Visual Studio also needs to run elevated (in case you cannot do that in your environment)

What's your goal? What are you trying to achieve? Why are you trying to send the down arrow key in task manager?

I did also try using admin and it did not work. Also that is my goal, using the navigation feature on task manager.

@Developer: using the navigation feature on task manager: What navigation feature? How would automating a down arrow keypress in Task Manager be useful to anyone? Please elaborate.

Task Manager is not an API. It can and does change its UI regularly, and when that happens, your program will stop working. What is the information from Task Manager that you are trying to replicate?

@RaymondChen I am trying to simulate a navigation through task manager

That says "what" you want to do, but not "why". Why are you navigating through Task Manager? Is it to extract data from it? In which case, you should use the APIs to retrieve that data directly rather than laundering it through Task Manager, so that your program keeps working even if Task Manager changes, or [gasp] is disabled by the administrator.

@RaymondChen I want to navigate into it by simulating key presses. My goal is to get the navigation to work using a simulated tab press. Not to extract data.

Since you don’t know what page Task Manager is on, you don’t know what the down arrow will do, so why send it?

Your unwillingness to provide more information about your intentions makes it seem like you are doing this for nefarious purposes. Perhaps you're creating malware or a virus, and want to monitor if Task Manager is opened. If so, use the up-arrow or down_arrow to prevent someone from selecting the desired line making it difficult to kill the process. If not, please explain what your motivation for attempting to do this is.
